# Why FileNotFound for method arguments inside main.py

Tags: python, class, import, arguments, filenotfounderror

I have this issue from the follow python project:

```
MyPackage
├──src
|  ├──cust_function.py ----> class, functions
|  ├──__init__.py
|  
|--data --> folder where store raw or processed data
|  |___init__.py
|  |
|---config -> setup folder
|  |-__init__.py
|  |-config.json -> API parameters
| 
└──main.py  -> main file
```

So, in the cust_function.py I have some classes and methods, like `with open(filepath)`

```
def get_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
       ....
    return ....
```

Now the issue come from main.py, if I send this request:

```
from src.cust_function import get_file

filepath = "config/config.json"
get_file(filepath)
```

The result is FileNotFoundError by config.json

I used os.path and sys.path in different ways and didn't work,

```
fpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src', 'config')
sys.path.append(fpath)
```

and also I used

```
sys.path.append(project_name), and doesn't

Or I put same sys.path in __init__.py into config or src folder.


Of course, I tried directly in the same main.py and it works.
The idea is to understand how call methods and send arguments, like filepath, from main script and cust_function works fine.

Thanks.
```

Comment: Where is the file that you want to read it ?

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), 'src', 'config')` order of arguments is probably wrong.

Comment: I edited the example. The filepath = "config/config.json". But I understand if main.py is in the root, I call folder and file, right?

Comment: @matszwecja Yes you're right, but with or without this line, facing same issue. Remove first 'src' or the second one, same FileNotFound.

Answer (score 1):

Adding non-python files to your packages is not that straight forward. You never know, from where your packages gets executed. Especially if you actually distribute the package later on.
For local use, have a look at importlib. I use the following code:

```py
from importlib import resources
import json

import config # your package

text = resources.read_text(config, "config.json")
conf = json.loads(text)
```

---

I assume you tweak sys.path to fix your imports? Is there a particular reason you use `MyPackage` as a Namespace Package (no `__init__.py`)? If you are working from the parent directory of MyPackage, you should be able to import all modules just fine using `from MyPackage.src import cust_function`. No need to adjust `sys.path`.

Else, if you want those sub packages to be separated (then MyPackage is a weird name for it not being a package), then being located in that directory should make all sub packages importable as is.

If you are located in an arbitrary location then you can `export PYTHONPATH=PathToParentDirOfMyPackage` or `export PYTHONPATH=PathToMyPackage` depending on the answer to the paragraphs above. Assuming you run on a Unix-based system (Linux, Mac) and in a shell.

Comment: But, inside a class or method file, I need to create **sys.path(....)** or not ? Because I call function or methods after instantiate the class object. 

`
filepath = "config/config.json"
get_file(filepath)
`
Also I tried with pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'config' / 'config.json' and didn't work.

Comment: Ok, same when I use API request. I need to configure from json file an header or body, right? So those files are external or non-python files, and I facing the same issues. I read the packaging section on Python documentation, but when project has different folders and subfolders, it's not clear how pass arguments like a filepath.

Comment: If you want to package your code, then you need to explicitly specify which non-python files need to go into the package as well. Either in the setup.py file or I believe some manifest file. Not 100% right now.

Comment: I am a bit confused by `But, inside a class or method file, I need to create sys.path(....) or not ?` Your python files are called modules. Those modules can contain classes and methods. I don't fully understand your use case but I usually don't have to mess with `sys.path`.